# Elasticsearch nested aggregation

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Example

```
  PRODUCT 1
       "attributes_list" : {
            "src1" : [
              {
                "aname" : "Manufacturer Standard Lead Time",
                "avalue" : "16 Weeks"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Color",
                "avalue" : "red"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Detailed Description",
                "avalue" : "Pre-Biased Bipolar
              },
              {
                "aname" : "DC Current Gain (hFE) (Min) @ Ic, Vce",
                "avalue" : "100 @ 10mA, 5V"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Transistor Type",
                "avalue" : "2 NPN - Pre-Biased (Dual)"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Mounting Type",
                "avalue" : "Surface Mount"
              }

            ],

           "src2" : [
              {
                "aname" : "Manufacturer Standard Lead Time",
                "avalue" : "16 Weeks"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Color",
                "avalue" : "red"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Detailed Description",
                "avalue" : "Pre-Biased Bipolar
              }

            ]
          },

PRODUCT 2-------------
       "attributes_list" : {
            "src1" : [
              {
                "aname" : "Lead Time",
                "avalue" : "16 Weeks"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Color",
                "avalue" : "green"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Description",
                "avalue" : "Pre-Biased Bipolar
              },
              {
                "aname" : "DC Current Gain (hFE) ",
                "avalue" : "100 @ 10mA, 5V"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Transistor",
                "avalue" : "2 NPN - Pre-Biased (Dual)"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Type",
                "avalue" : "Surface Mount"
              }

            ],

           "src2" : [
              {
                "aname" : "Lead Time",
                "avalue" : "16 Weeks"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Color",
                "avalue" : "green"
              },
              {
                "aname" : "Description",
                "avalue" : "Pre-Biased Bipolar
              }

            ]
          },
```

How to create mapping for this kind of field data?
We need to achieve something like..
For products filters we need to show the aggregation

In the above 2 products the aname COLOR is available on both products attributes list. We need to get color (doc_count=2) etc to list the most common attributes for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your data is certainly of type `nested`. In Elasticsearch, there is no specific data type for a list, so in general, the first item in the list will defined its mapping type, if you did not explicitly specify the mapping.

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "attributes_list": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "src1": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "aname": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "avalue": {
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "src2": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "aname": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "avalue": {
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```